# Битрикс отправка номера телефона в email о заказе

Tags: php, битрикс

Пробовал добавлять в init.php

```
AddEventHandler("sale", "OnOrderNewSendEmail", "modifySendingSaleData");
function modifySendingSaleData($orderID, &$eventName, &$arFields) {
    // инициализируем 

    $phone = '';


    // получаем параметры заказа по ID
    $arOrder = CSaleOrder::GetByID($orderID);

    // получаем свойства заказа
    $orderProps = CSaleOrderPropsValue::GetOrderProps($orderID);


    while ($arProps = $orderProps->Fetch()) {
        // телефон
        if ($arProps['CODE'] == 'PHONE') {
            $phone = htmlspecialchars($arProps['VALUE']);
        }
    }

     $arFields['PHONE'] = $phone;

}
```

к сожалению телефон так и не подтянуло
версия 1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом 17.0.0.
айди поля с телефоном в польз. полях PHONE
может я где-то ошибся? или что-то изменилось в 17 версии

Comment: Найдите шаблон почтовый шаблон, который битрикс отправляет. В Вашем случае можно обойтись его редактированием. В админке в настройках есть пункт, почтовые событие как-то так и там есть шаблоны сообщений по всем событиям.

Comment: @NikolajSarry я знаю о них. просто по умолчанию Битрикс не подгружает данные из всех полей. емейл доступен, имя, пунктов 10 есть. но телефона нету

Comment: Проверьте соответствие полей формы полям заказа.

Comment: `Примечание: перечисленные ниже события устарели с версии 15.5.0, но в продукте сохранена обратная совместимость. Поэтому их можно использовать, если в настройках модуля Интернет-магазин отмечена опция Включить обработку устаревших событий. Либо вы можете использовать события нового ядра.` Стоит у вас опция?